# LINQ Any failing?

Tags: c#, linq, any

Is there any reason why the `Any` function in the following code could fail?

```
var orders = db.Order.Where(order => order.Item.Any());
foreach (var order in orders)
{
    var first = order.Item.First();  // NullReferenceException thrown here: order.Item == null
}
```

Maybe I'm simply misunderstanding something here, but it seems to me `order.Item` should never be null due to the earlier `Any` statement.

Edit: if I make sure the expression is evaluated and not deferred by putting a `ToList` there, I get another exception due to the `order.Item` sequence having no items, which also baffles me:

```
var orders = db.Order.Where(order => order.Item.Any()).ToList();
foreach (var order in orders)
{
    var first = order.Item.First();  // System.InvalidOperationException thrown here: order.Item.Count == 0
}
```

Comment: what is type of `order.Item`?

Comment: It is `Item`, stemming from an `Item` table in my model. Orders can have 0 to n Items

Comment: are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: "Item" is not an structure, right?

Comment: @Adil: No, my model code is generated using SQLMetal.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Ah, that was sloppy. In the question code, yes. In my actual code, no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression that computes `orders` is *deferred*, so when there are any `null`s in `db.Order`'s `Item`, you wouldn't find them until you are in the `foreach` loop.

You can see what's going on by adding a `ToList()` call:

```
var orders = db.Order.Where(order => order.Item.Any()).ToList();
```

Now the exception will be thrown before the loop.

You can fix this by adding an explicit `null` check in the `Where` condition, or by using the new `?.` syntax of C# 6:

```
var orders = db.Order.Where(order => order.Item != null && order.Item.Any());
```

or

```
var orders = db.Order.Where(order => order?.Item.Any());
```

The `order.Item.Count == 0` error may be of the same nature: since the check for `Any()` is done at the DB level, and the call for `First()` happens at some later time, chances are that the item that was there for `Any()` to succeed is gone by the time you call `First()`.

You should be able to fix this by adding `LoadWith` option for `Item`.

Comment: I thought this was exactly what was happening, but it's not quite the complete story. I've updated my question, as I still don't see how the `Any` could be executed, but then have `order.Item` with no items.

Comment: @Protectorone I think the fundamental problem is the same - the check and the loading are executed at different times. You should be able to fix this by loading `Item` eagerly.

Comment: Using `DataLoadOptions` and `LoadWidth` indeed fixed the problem! Is there any way I could have anticipated this problem beforehand? I'm used to LINQ automatically loading whatever entities are needed…

Comment: @Protectorone Unfortunately, this is one of these nasty situations when it's very hard to anticipate errors due to a big number of moving parts. In a way, problems like this are easier to fix than to anticipate.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
var orders = db.Order.Where(order => order.Item.Any());
```

won't actually evaluate until it needs to, so appears to fail later on.

If you replace the line with:

```
var orders = db.Order.Where(order => order.Item.Any()).ToList();
```

you'll see the failure immediately as the query is evaluated when the list is generated.

Replace the line with:

```
var orders = db.Order.Where(order => order.Item != null && order.Item.Any());
```

and it should work OK

Comment: This is not quite right yet. I've updated my question with the new exception I'm receiving if I put a `ToList` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler than you think.
According to the [definition of Enumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) the ArgumentNullException is thrown if source is null.

Your class Order has a property Order.Item. One of your orders has an Item with value null. Your code should be:

```
var orders = db.Order.Where(order => order.Item != null && order.Item.Any());
```